# .htaccess rules causing internal server error yet they look right

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My server's. htaccess rules look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# first redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.testing\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing\.examplewebsite\.co\uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testing.examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# second redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.examplewebsite\.co\uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Main redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplewebsite\.co\uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# All subdomains that don't exist redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.examplewebsite.com/  [L,R]
```

But for some reason none it causes a server internal error, I'm not sure if they are all 100% correct either. Like the last rule, should that too use `^(.*)$` at the start and `$1` at the end

Same for the flags, not too sure if they are all correct.

Basically I am trying to make:

- `testing.examplewebsite.co.uk` and `www.testing.examplewebsite.co.uk` go to `https://testing.examplewebsite.com`
- `test.examplewebsite.co.uk` and `www.test.examplewebsite.co.uk` go to `https://test.examplewebsite.com`
- Some other subdomains like above
- `examplewebsite.co.uk` and `www.examplewebsite.co.uk` go to `https://examplewebsite.com`
- Make all used domains, for example `stackoverflow.examplewebsite.co.uk` and `www.stackoverflow.examplewebsite.co.uk` both be sent to `https://examplewebsite.com`

Comment: Did you .htaccess work before you added these rules? And did you check your error log?

Comment: Yes, no errors in my log :(

Comment: You can't be looking at the correct apache log. It will show why there is a 500 error. Most likely it could be it doesn't recognize `RewriteEngine` Remove the first line RewriteEngine and see if you still get an error.

Comment: @PanamaJack Ahh in Apache logs, yes it says: `RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '^testing\\.examplewebsite\\.co\\uk$'`

Comment: `\u` is a special escape sequence for entering unicode characters and should be followed by 4 hex digits. (Although I'm not even sure that Apache supports this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in all of your conditions. the 2nd conditions in your lines is missing a `.` before `uk`. ^testing.examplewebsite.co.uk$ [NC]

```
RewriteEngine On
# first redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.testing\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testing.examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# second redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Main redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplewebsite\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# All subdomains that don't exist redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.examplewebsite\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.examplewebsite.com/  [L,R]
```

Comment: What about that last rule, should I be using `^` or `^(.*)$` or something else, I don't understand what that part of the rewrite rule is for. Other than that, yeah I see the mistake now. How embarrassing.

Comment: In the last line, that only matters if you also want to redirect any files or subfolders too. Since those subdomains don't exist you should leave the last rule as is.